# Is there a way to get the password on a failed wordpress login?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I need to get the password from a failed login attempt in WordPress but I don't know how, I'm using the action wp_failed_login to hook into this but when I do:

```
add_action('wp_login_failed', 'login_failed_func'); 

function login_failed_func($args){ 
    var_dump($args);
}
```

It only returns the username, does anyone know what I should do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adjust your function like this:

```
add_action('wp_login_failed', 'login_failed_func'); 

function login_failed_func($args) { 
    var_dump($args);
    echo "\n<br />"."password = ". $_POST['pwd']."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Perfect this worked, I tried using $_post['user_pass'] but this was the id not the name. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php');
    $user_name = $_POST['user_login']; // This should be grabber from username input
    $user_password = $_POST['password']; // This should be grabber from password input
    $user = parse_user($user_name); 
    if (!wp_check_password($user_password, $user->user_pass)) {
        echo 'wrong password'; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, $_POST['user_login'] and $_POST['password'] appears to be empty, what I need to do is log the username and password that the user typed when the login failed, I know how to get the username but not the password.

Comment: Well replace these with your own input names.

Comment: I tried $_post['user_pass'] but this was the id, it was actually $_POST['pwd']